# Haskell: Is it possible to create a list of Show types? List[Show]?

Tags: haskell

Is possible to create a list which holds values that belong to the `Show` type ?

This would be something similar to `List[Showable]` in Scala, where `Showable` is a trait.

In this way one could put, for example,  `Int` and `String` into the **same** list.

Is this possible? If yes, how ?

Comment: By the way, in Haskell, `Show` is not a type, but a typeclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [existential types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types)

```
data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s

heteroList :: [ShowBox]
heteroList = [SB "Hello world", SB 5, SB 1]
```

the only thing you can do with the items in this list is `show` them:

```
let strings = fmap (\(SB b) -> show b) heteroList
```

Comment: You might wanna add a note on how that's probably not actually what he wants to do.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Showable where Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable
foo = [Showable 3, Showable "foo", Showable ()]
```

But may I suggest just using `[String]` instead, or perhaps a `[Int -> ShowS]` if you really need the fanciness of `showsPrec`, since all you can do with such a list is show the things inside?

```
foo' = [show 3, show "foo", show ()]
```